# Get how many times a word appears in a text file and link it to a text file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I currently have 3 text files with the data

> Textfile1
> Hello World
> Bye World
>
> Textfile2
> Hello World
> Hello Second

How do I get a result of

> Hello {Textfile1 = 1, Textfile2 =2}
> World {Textfile1 = 2, Textfile2 = 1}

Currently I have managed to pass the words from my Map into my Reduce java page. This is where I am stuck at at the moment.

```
public class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    HashMap<Text, Integer>input = new HashMap<Text, Integer>();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values , Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for(Text val: values){
            String word = key.toString();
            Text filename;
            input.put(val,sum );
                if(//not sure what to write here){
                 
               }
            }
       context.write(new Text(key), input);
}
```

My mapper code

```
public class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

private Text file = new Text();
private Text word = new Text();
private String pattern= "^[a-z][a-z0-9]*$";//any lower case letter or number

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    
    InputSplit inputSplit = context.getInputSplit();
    String fileName = ((FileSplit)inputSplit).getPath().getName();
    file.set(fileName);
    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
       word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
        
        String stringWord = word.toString().toLowerCase();
        if (stringWord.matches(pattern)){
            context.write(new Text(stringWord), new Text(fileName));
            
        }
    }
}
```

}

Hope I can get some help

Comment: How do you pass input from all the three files? do you have a separate mapper for each file? It would be better if you could post your mapper code.

Comment: Hi, I have added my mapper code. It sends a Text, Text format into reduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In output of the mapper we can set the text file name as key and each row in the file as the value.

The file name can be retrieved using the below code snippet in Mapper class.

```
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
```

Then in the reducer

```
public class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
HashMap<Text, Integer>input = new HashMap<Text, Integer>();

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values , Context context)
throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int sum = 0;
    for(Text val: values){
        String word = val.toString(); -- processing each row
        String[] wordarray = word.split(' ');
        for(int i=0 ; i<wordarray.length; i++)
       {
        if(input.get(wordarray[i]) == null){
        input.put(wordarray[i],1);}
        else{
         int value =input.get(wordarray[i]) +1 ; 
         input.put(wordarray[i],value);
         }
       }     

   context.write(new Text(key), new Text(input.toString()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, context.write is giving an error saying it cannot fir the argument (Text, Hashmap) into (Text,Text). I'm not sure how i can still put the hashmap there @madhu

Comment: Convert the hashmap to a string and cast it as Text.

Comment: But don't I need to insert an int in order to do calculations as well?

Comment: if you want to do further calculations from this output you can format the data as per the need in your second mapper

Comment: Sorry I'm not so clear on what to do. Could you edit the answer? And I have inserted my mapper code in case that changes anything.

Comment: Just change the stringword as key and file name as value. And have edited the answer as per your need.

Comment: Its showing that I have anull pointer exception in the line where it says if(input.get(wordarray[i]) == 0){. Not sure why

Comment: It doesn't seem to be adding up anything. Everything is showing 1. I'm trying to see if the values are the issue. It doesn't seem to be called.

Comment: This solution is the closest one. However the output will be 1 no matter what.

Comment: Can we have the hashmap to have string as the key instead of text and do the necessary changes in the reducer code....

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom writable class for map key. Something like a [textpair](https://gist.github.com/iceboal/4440822) which would hold filename,word and value would be 1.

Map Output

```
<K,V> ==> <MytextpairWritable,new IntWritable(1)>
```

And just sum up the value in the reducer side and emit the value. Something like this.

```
public class Reduce extends Reducer<mytextpairWritable, IntWritable,mytextpairWritable, IntWritable> {


    public void reduce(mytextpairWritable key, Iterable<IntWritable> values , Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for(IntWritable val: values){
            sum+=val.get();
            }
       context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
}
```

This would give you something like

```
File1,hello,2
File2,hello,3
File3,hello,1
```